# Regex match one but not another

Tags: regex, bash

So i have this log file

```
2017-06-14 08:53:41,472 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:41,472 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:41,472 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:45,010 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-05-23 18:38:35,966 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 52228 200 0 159 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:37,811 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 53716 200 0 301 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-06-14 08:53:45,010 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:45,011 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:45,011 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 09:40:04,506 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 58.0 
2017-06-14 12:32:40,779 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0
2017-06-14 13:22:40,988 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:24:45,023 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:25:16,091 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:26:18,138 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-05-23 18:38:34,874 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 673 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:35,428 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 662 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:57,901 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 745 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-06-14 13:27:20,425 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:28:22,237 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:28:53,225 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:29:24,139 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:32:30,227 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-05-23 18:38:33,881 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 603 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:34,111 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 675 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:34,144 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 481 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-06-14 13:33:01,250 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:35:05,346 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:36:07,563 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:39:13,557 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:39:33,777 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 58.0
2017-05-23 18:38:58,445 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 859 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:58,485 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 819 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:58,720 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 654 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:58,760 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 624 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-06-14 13:39:44,517 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:45:25,661 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:46:58,629 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:49:02,639 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:49:40,884 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-05-23 18:38:34,369 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 683 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:58,181 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 886 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-05-23 18:38:58,210 - [info] access - example.com "GET HTTP/1.1" 662 304 0 0 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
2017-06-14 13:50:04,713 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:50:27,767 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:50:27,767 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 13:50:27,767 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Internet Explorer 11.0
2017-06-14 14:04:44,239 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: PhantomJS 2.1
```

I would like to find all the errors in the file with one regex but NOT the error lines that contain "Internet Explorer 11".

Using regex101.com I was able to figure out this regex I was able to find a regex that matches this: `(\[.*error.*\])(?!.*Internet Explorer 11.*)`

[regex101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBGZ0.png)

Now I'm wondering how I can execute this on the command line to test this.

what I tried

These shows no output (had to escape the `!`

`grep "(\[.*error.*\]){1,}(?\!.*Internet Explorer 11.*)" /var/log/upstart/app.log`

`egrep "(\[.*error.*\]){1,}(?\!.*Internet Explorer 11.*)" /var/log/upstart/app.log`

Anyone know how to do this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: As an aside, escaping the `!` is somewhat hard to do, `"!foo"` would try history expansion, and `"\!foo"` prints both the backslash and exclamation point. The solution is to use single quotes, or disable history expansion completely.

Comment: Why do you need a single regex?  Is there some reason you can't `grep -F '[error]' | grep -v -F 'Internet Explorer 11'` for example?

Answer (score 1):

The lookahead patterns like `(?!...)` are specific to Perl regexes, and not part of the usual Basic and Extended regexes that `grep` uses.

But what you want is easy to do with grep and a pipeline:

```
grep -F '[error]' /var/log/upstart/app.log | grep -vF 'Internet Explorer 11'
```

Or you could use [`grep -P`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) (with GNU grep) or [`pcregrep`](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html), they support Perl regexes:

```
pcregrep '(\[.*error.*\])(?!.*Internet Explorer 11.*)' /var/log/upstart/app.log
```

<sub>(GNU grep's manual mentions that `-P` is "highly experimental", but it's not exactly a new feature, and in practice seems to work fine.)</sub>

Comment: Even though this solution works, I need it to be in one regex because I have to pass it into a tool that parses regex's and there is only one input field. I just wanted to see how I could test it with grep.

Comment: @Firewall, then `pcregrep` or `grep -P` it is. Assuming the tool you're using uses Perl-compatible regexes too, because if not, the pattern isn't going to work there either.

Answer (score 0):

With single ***awk*** command:

```
awk '$4~/error/ && $0!~/Internet Explorer 11/' file
```

The output:

```
2017-06-14 08:53:41,472 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:41,472 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:41,472 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:45,010 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:45,010 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:45,011 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 08:53:45,011 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0 
2017-06-14 09:40:04,506 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 58.0 
2017-06-14 12:32:40,779 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 57.0
2017-06-14 13:39:33,777 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: Chrome 58.0
2017-06-14 14:04:44,239 - [error] javascript - "Javascript error: undefined - url: undefined - line: undefined - browser: PhantomJS 2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways with piping and excluding using a switch for grep (-v)... but if you did want a pure regex solution:

```
grep -P '^((?!Internet\ Explorer\ 11).)*\[error\]((?!Internet\ Explorer\ 11).)*$' filename
```

here -P uses the perl regex which I think is necessary for lookahead

Comment: Great! If it works for you, please vote or accept my answer!

Comment: Great! If it works for you, please vote or accept my answer!